# python: multi-threading inside a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have to solve a system of ODE using a fix time step. At each time step, I must compute the output of a number of similar equations (I am programming a neural network and I must compute the value of each neuron. Those neurons are represented by a system of ODE). Thus I would like to parallel the computations inside the loop. I tried using the threading package but I should have done something wrong because it does not work... (In the following code, I skip the generation of the input for clarity)

```
class EBNMCPU(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, Ts, OnDir):
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.Neuron=NM.EBN(Ts,Dir=OnDir)
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
  def run(self,Glu=[np.array([1.0],dtype='float'),0.0],GlyOPN=np.array([1.0],dtype='float'),GlyIBN=np.array([0.0],dtype='float')):
    threadLock.acquire()
    self.Neuron.NextStep(Glu, GlyOPN, GlyIBN)
    threadLock.release()

  def getOutput(self):
    return self.Neuron.getOutput()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Ts=np.array( [0.005] , dtype=float)

  threadLock = threading.Lock()
  EBN=[]
  for ii in np.arange(0,10):
      EBN.append(EBNMCPU(ii,Ts,OnDir=0.0))

  for tc in EBN:
    tc.start() 

  for ii in np.arange(0,NSample):
    for tc in EBN:
      tc.run([np.array([AllY[ii,1]]),0.0],np.array([AllY[ii,2]]),np.array([AllY[ii,3]]))

    for tc in EBN:
      tc.join()
```

The problem is that I do not see any parallel activity in my system manager...

Thank you for your comments/help,

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I do not see any parallel activity in my system manager

That's because Python threads do not distribute over multiple CPUs/cores due to the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`joblib`](http://packages.python.org/joblib/) to write parallel Python programs.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `run()` directly, which run the code in the same thread. `run()` must have no parameter. You should pass every argument when constructing the object then call `start()` to run it in a new thread.